# ALTER TABLE DROP INDEX failed on a table that isn't memory optimized

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, memory-optimized-tables

I'm trying to drop an index created on a table, but I get this error -

> The operation 'ALTER TABLE DROP INDEX' is supported only with memory optimized tables.

I need to remove this index in order to drop a field in my table. Is there any way of doing this without duplicating the table, and migrating all the data across?

Answer (score 22):

For regular tables you should use [`DROP INDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) syntax:

```
DROP INDEX index_name ON tab_name;
```

> [`ALTER TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> The syntax ALTER TABLE ... ADD/DROP/ALTER INDEX **is supported only for memory-optimized tables.**

Answer (score 6):

To Drop an Index

```
DROP INDEX index_name ON table_name
```

To Add an Index

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name(column1, column2, ...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Drop index on memory optimized table can be done only using alter table statement

Alter table  table name DROP INDEX index name

or non memory optimized tables

DROP INDEX index name ON table name

Memory optimized tables are being supported from sql server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/altering-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-2017): if it is NOT a memory optimized table then just use the "drop index" statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need use
`Drop Index <IndexName> On <TableName>`

Comment: Hi Sanjoy, thanks for your answer. Can you update your question to explain **why** this solves the asker's issue? A good start is linking to the docs and quoting an important bit of context.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28329818)

Comment: @Oliver How is this a comment. It is definitely answer. It might not be a very good answer, but it is an answer nonetheless.

Comment: You are most definitely correct. I was a bit hasty on my review queue, and this looked mostly like something one should be putting in the comment.